# Is there a way to use redquerybuilder with Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene, redquerybuilder

Is there any interface to Lucene from redquery builder (https://github.com/salk31/RedQueryBuilder)? I have a Lucene indexed system and would like to support complex Lucene queries using its AND and NOT operators.

Alternatively, are there other visual query builders out there for Lucene that support "advanced search" functionality that include arbitrary numbers of AND/OR clauses?

Comment: What's wrong with Lucene's QueryParser? You can always build your own using Lucene's BooleanQuery

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't one that exists already.

I can think of two options:
* Use a SQL parser and serialiser to transform SQL into Lucence syntax (or query objects on the server)
* Use the 0.8.0 custom serialiser in RQB to produce Lucence query string. NB This is very experimental feature.

I should declare that I started the RQB project and that I love Lucence. Maybe worth raising a ticket for a feature? It could be a good way to test the serialisation if it produces Lucence queries rather than SQL?

NB If you want to store/re-load queries RQB is only designed to use SQL. It was chosen as a standard language to load/save even if never gets executed.